# Turn dataframe into list per row creating a vector per row in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector, type-conversion

I have the following dataframe df (way bigger in reality):

```
      A       B       C
1   ORp0    RT1p20  RT2p20  
2   RT3p0   RT4p0   RT5p0   
3   RT3p0   RT4p0   RT5p05
```

I need to turn this into an object so the structure looks like this

```
str(df)

List of 3
 $ : chr [1:3] "ORp0"  "RT1p20" "RT2p20"
 $ : chr [1:3] "RT3p0" "RT4p0"  "RT5p0"
 $ : chr [1:3] "RT3p0" "RT4p0"  "RT5p05"
```

It seems that every row of this list is a vector. How can I achieve this tranformation from a dataframe?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(A = c("ORp0", "RT3p0", "RT3p0"), B = c("RT1p20", 
"RT4p0", "RT4p0"), C = c("RT2p20", "RT5p0", "RT5p05")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Code:

```
List <- split(df,rownames(df))
```

Output:

```
List
$`1`
     A      B      C
1 ORp0 RT1p20 RT2p20

$`2`
      A     B     C
2 RT3p0 RT4p0 RT5p0

$`3`
      A     B      C
3 RT3p0 RT4p0 RT5p05
```

If you wanna format further you can use next code:

```
L2 <- lapply(List, function(x) {y <- c(t(x[1,])); return(y)})
```

That will output:

```
L2
$`1`
[1] "ORp0"   "RT1p20" "RT2p20"

$`2`
[1] "RT3p0" "RT4p0" "RT5p0"

$`3`
[1] "RT3p0"  "RT4p0"  "RT5p05"
```

Similar to what you want. Just as observation be careful with rownames and check that they start from 1 to last observation in your dataframe. Sometimes they can be different!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `split`:

```
new_list <- split(as.matrix(df), row(df))
new_list
$`1`
[1] "ORp0"   "RT1p20" "RT2p20"

$`2`
[1] "RT3p0" "RT4p0" "RT5p0"

$`3`
[1] "RT3p0"  "RT4p0"  "RT5p05"

str(new_list)
List of 3
 $ 1: chr [1:3] "ORp0" "RT1p20" "RT2p20"
 $ 2: chr [1:3] "RT3p0" "RT4p0" "RT5p0"
 $ 3: chr [1:3] "RT3p0" "RT4p0" "RT5p05"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following options:

- `asplit` + `unname`

```
> str(Map(unname,asplit(df,1)))
List of 3
 $ 1: chr [1:3(1d)] "ORp0" "RT1p20" "RT2p20"
 $ 2: chr [1:3(1d)] "RT3p0" "RT4p0" "RT5p0"
 $ 3: chr [1:3(1d)] "RT3p0" "RT4p0" "RT5p05"
```

or a simpler one (by @akrun in the comment)

```
> str(asplit(unname(df),1))
List of 3
 $ 1: chr [1:3(1d)] "ORp0" "RT1p20" "RT2p20"
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : NULL
 $ 2: chr [1:3(1d)] "RT3p0" "RT4p0" "RT5p0"
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : NULL
 $ 3: chr [1:3(1d)] "RT3p0" "RT4p0" "RT5p05"
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : NULL
 - attr(*, "dim")= int 3
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
```

- `unclass` + `as.data.frame` + `t`

```
> str(unclass(as.data.frame(t(df))))
List of 3
 $ 1: chr [1:3] "ORp0" "RT1p20" "RT2p20"
 $ 2: chr [1:3] "RT3p0" "RT4p0" "RT5p0"
 $ 3: chr [1:3] "RT3p0" "RT4p0" "RT5p05"
 - attr(*, "row.names")= chr [1:3] "A" "B" "C"
```

Comment: You could use `asplit(unname(df), 1)`

Comment: @akrun Thanks! Yours is concise :)